# Override only few JSON keys using 'CodingKeys' enum

Tags: swift, codable

I'm parsing JSON data using `Codables`. Problem is that my few coding keys are different from variable names. For that i used `CodingKeys` enum which is pretty much straight forward, however i have to write all keys then, i don't want that. I only want to override few keys not all.

here's the JSON

```
{
   "string_one" = "some string",
   "string_two" = "some string",
   "string_three_%s" = "some string",
}
```

```
class Strings: Codable{

    var string_one: String?
    var string_two: String?
    var string_three: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case string_three = "string_three_%s"
    }
}
```

**More Explanation**

i know that adding `case string_one, string_two` will work but let's say i have 1000 strings and want to override just one, i have to write 999 cases without any reason. It does not look like a sensible thing to me(to writing 999 cases without any reason)

Answer (score 0):

As of now this is not possible. You have to specify all the `cases` in `CodingKeys`.

Just that for others you don't need to specify the `rawValue` explicitly since the `enum CodingKeys` has raw type as `String` and will pick the `case` name as the default `rawValue`, i.e.

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case string_three = "string_three_%s"
    case string_one, string_two
}
```

Comment: let's say i have 1000 strings and want to override just one, i have to write 999 cases without any reason. It does not look like a sensible thing to me(to writing 999 cases without any reason).

Comment: This is how `Codable` is designed by Apple as of now. You'll have to take this pain..:)

Comment: Well, i have added more explanation to my question, so that other people don't waste time adding answers to that. thanks anyway.

Comment: Sure. But anyways you cannot do it. `Codable` doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

The shorter answer is that you cannot do it. This can be only done by putting all cases as below :-

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case string_one, string_two
        case string_three = "string_three_%s"
    }
```

The keys `string_one` and `string_two` will be picked as it is

Comment: Same as above one... but not my solution

let's say i have 1000 strings and want to override just one, i have to write 999 cases without any reason. It does not look like a sensible thing to me(to writing 999 cases without any reason)

Comment: @ChaudharyShahbazSaleem The coding keys works the same way as above. There is no option. Shorter answer is you can't do it.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava Kindly don't add duplicate answers.

Comment: @PGDev Didn't copied your simple answer, might be added at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this proper form of modal class.
Hope you get your solution**

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let stringOne, stringTwo, stringThreeS: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case stringOne = "string_one"
        case stringTwo = "string_two"
        case stringThreeS = "string_three_%s"
    }
}
```

Comment: appreciated, but i question is different. please read again...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set All coding keys in order to work as of now.

The class will only Encode/Decode, the keys you described in enum `CodingKeys`.

If you have larger number of strings, I'd suggest you to communicate with Server team for create an Array of string(`[String]`) instead of this pattern.

---

Update: As you have high number of values, you should have gone for `[String]`

Comment: can't do that, as its kinda configuration data being fetched on app launch...
and we can't use by index.
However saving the dictionary as is can be a solution.

Comment: Yep. Or you have to specify all keys.

Comment: can we go for inheritance here. like non-overridable strings in parent class and overridable in child class. just a random idea... @lal-krishna

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion (not tested) but could you use a base class (which extends Codable) with the fields you don't want to override, then use a subclass which just has the names you need to override? I.e. does CodingKeys require you define values for inherited fields?

Comment: I tried that but CodingKeys only work for child class only. It doesn't parse parent keys.